# Library application

Tags: c#, class, arraylist

I'm writing a library application, I'm supposed to be able to write Title, author and then what type of book (Roman, Tidskrift, novellsamling).

The program is meant to when the 2 questions of title and author is asked, you have options 1-3, is the book type a 1. Roman 2. Tidskrift 3. Novellsamling.

You shall answer by either 1, 2 or 3. And when i then call the method VisaBöcker (ShowBooks in English), how do i make make it so it has saved my option of 1,2 or 3, and it being saved in the option the user wants to save it as, in other words, if I choose 1 for Roman, how do I make "1" being saved to the Roman class? So it displays `"Title" + "Author" + "Type (1,2,3 / Roman,Tidskrift,Novellsamling)`, example: `Pippi Långstrump by Astrid Lindgren. (Roman) <- the type of book, number 1 chosen.`

Right now I can type out the word Roman when you get asked which type of book it is, but you are supposed to only write 1,2 or 3 as the options, and it shall save it on that class you want it to, Roman for example.

```
class Bok
{
    public string Titel = "";
    public string Skribent = "";
    public string Typ;

    class Roman : Bok
    {
        public Roman()
        {
            Typ = "Roman";
        }
    }

    class Tidskrift : Bok
    {
        public Tidskrift()
        {
            Typ = "Tidskrift";
        }
    }

    class Novellsamling : Bok
    {
        public Novellsamling()
        {
            Typ = "Novellsamling";
        }
    }
}

static List<string[]> Böcker = new List<string[]>();
static string[] bok;

public static void RegistreraBok()
{
    bok = new string[3];

    Console.Write("\n\tSkriv in titel: ");
    bok[0] = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("\n\tSkriv in författare: ");
    bok[1] = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("\n\tÄr boken en [1] Roman, [2] Tidsskrift eller [3] Novellsamling?: ");
    bok[2] = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("\n\tSparat!");
    Console.ReadLine();

    Böcker.Add(bok);
    Console.Clear();
}

public static void VisaBöcker()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Böcker.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + Böcker[i][0] + " av " + Böcker[i][1] + "." + " ( " + Böcker[i][2] + " )");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modified your code this way(https://pastebin.com/fz4i1p0P)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<book> _booksList = new List<book>();
        static Hashtable _ht = new Hashtable();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _ht.Add(BookTypes.Roman, "Roman");
            _ht.Add(BookTypes.Journal, "Journal");
            _ht.Add(BookTypes.StoryCollection, "Collection of stories");

            Console.WriteLine("\t Hello and welcome to the library!");
            int userInput;
            bool isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t[1] Add a book" +
                    "\n\t[2] Show Books" +
                    "\n\t[3] End program");
                Console.Write("\n\tSelect: ");
                Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);
                switch (userInput)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        RegisterBook();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        ShowAllBooks();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        isRunning = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tDu kan endast välja 1-3 i menyn.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        static void RegisterBook()
        {
            book bok = new book();
            Console.Write("\n\tEnter Title: ");
            bok.Title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("\n\t Author : ");
            bok.Author = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("\n\tEnter Type of book - Roman-1, Journal-2, Collection of stories-3?: ");
            bok.BookType = (BookTypes)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            _booksList.Add(bok);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t Added Book Successfully !");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        public static void ShowAllBooks()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _booksList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" +" Title: "+ _booksList[i].Title + " Author: " + _booksList[i].Author+ " Type: " + _ht[_booksList[i].BookType].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public class book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public BookTypes BookType { get; set; }
    }
    public enum BookTypes
    {
        Roman=1,
        Journal=2,
        StoryCollection=3
    }
}
```

please check and let me know

Comment: Wow thank you very very much, i will check it out more detailed soon, looks like it works perfectly, i will add my 'touch' of style and writing/language. I will let you know if something is up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using classes to represent Book Types, you can try Enum in the following way

```
public enum BookTypes
{
    Roman =1,
    Tidskrift=2,
    Novellsamling=3

}
```

And in your function, you can try this

```
        BookTypes eTypes = BookTypes.Novellsamling;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Type of Book: = "); 
        eTypes = (BookTypes) Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
        Console.WriteLine("Type: = " + eTypes.ToString());
```

Comment: I can't seem a way to fit that into my code, haven't used enum before. https://pastebin.com/dZKnGVrT , this is what my code looks like all in all, where would i put that code and what do i replace? I only get error that BookTypes could not be found + does not exist in the current context.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Xqc4AsXv now i found a way, however, when im gonna write out all of the books with the title, author and then the type of the book, i don't know what to type in the WriteLine by the "VisaBöcker()" which is show books, "type of book?" is where the type of the book is meant to be displayed, so if u chose 1, it shall say "Roman" there.

eTypes.ToString()); doesn't work there because it doesn't exist in the current context. It works in the RegisteraBok, but there eTypes = (BookTypes)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); exists.